# Data in subquery not recognized as number?

Tags: sql-server

I have created a View based on several tables generated by an application I use at work. The SQL generating the View contains a lot of CASE WHEN expressions as the raw tables lacks some of the logic needed for the reports I run.

One of the things I do is that I want 0 values in some columns when one Item does not match between tables.

```
case when e.Item=p.Item then p.ColumnA else 0 end as NewColumnA
```

ColumnA has data type FLOAT and it seems like NewColumA is FLOAT as well. But when I run a query on the View and  specify that I do not want records where NewColumnA is zero it runs extremely slow. However, if I add a ROUND outside the CASE WHEN in the VIEW it runs much faster (80s vs 0.5s).

```
round(case when e.Item=p.Item then p.ColumnA else 0 end,6) as NewColumnA
```

Now, this solves my performance issue, but I assume that this is hardly a "best practice" way of solving it. I am also extremely interested in knowing what is the problem.

Comment: can you try case when e.Item=p.Item then p.ColumnA else 0.0 end as NewColumnA? notice the 0.0

Comment: can you provide  sample data of e.Item,p.Item ??

Comment: Tom: It does not matter if it is 0 or 0.0, ist still runs slow. ROUND works well, but I fail to understand why it reduces the time so much.

Comment: Arunprasanth: It is a currency code, for example EUR or USD. The problem seems to be related to the data type of NewColumnA after it has been calculated.

Answer (score 0):

Using queries on a computed values in a view, will slow down your query, since it needs to do all calculations in the view before it can do the comparison.

Include e.Item and p.Item in your view under different alias, in this demonstration I use e_item and p_item.

Apply this to the WHERE clause, and don't include NewColumnA in your WHERE clause:

```
WHERE
  exists(SELECT e_item EXCEPT SELECT p_item)
```

Using the above syntax to prevent NULL values giving the wrong result.

If your columns never contains null, you can simply use

```
WHERE
  e_item <> p_item
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that would be too risky as it would mean that I would have misleading data on the View. As several people are making their own SQLs built on the View it would be difficult to get them to remember to add those lines to all their SQLs. The version I have with ROUND works, I just feel that it is not the best way of solving the issue.

Comment: adding regular columns to a view is NOT risky. You wanted the best practice method. This is it.

Comment: Not from from a data point of view, but in case of making it user friendly it is.